# How to edit File in perfoce with node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, perforce

If i have the code below how can i edit the specific file and make the right corrections?

```
    var p4 = require('C:/Program Files/nodejs/node_modules/p4');
    var File = process.argv[2]; 
    p4.edit(File, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
        }
            console.log(data);

    });
```

Comment: Maybe you could post a link to the Perforce node.js module you're using?  I don't think Perforce supplies one.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/p4#p4runcommand-args-done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks correct to open the file for edit.  If that returns any errors when you run it, you should post those here, but I'll assume that it returns a success message ("(file) opened for edit").

Opening the file for edit means that it is made writable on the local filesystem (i.e. the one where this code is running -- the file is the one you passed as an argument to the edit command).  To actually modify the file you can use any other function at your disposal.

Comment: Command failed: p4 edit 
Usage: add/edit/delete [-c changelist#] [ -d -f -I -k -n -v ] [-t type] files...
Missing/wrong number of arguments.

Comment: It looks like there is missing argument (changelist) i guess i need to insert it in somehow.

Comment: The only required argument is a filename -- I'm guessing your File variable is empty?